# L2TP over IPSec VPN established successfully on main router/firewall, how to access second layer router and its devices?

Tags: networking, vpn, l2tp

I apologize if the question doesn't make a lot of sense. Let me explain.
I have two routers with a setup like this:

ISP-provided modem configured as bridge mode, connected to a TP-Link router TL-ER3220G, which does PPPoE to connect to internet. This router also acts as the firewall and personal VPN server. DHCP is on, range between 192.168.1.0/24. It only has one client, 192.168.1.2, which is the second router.
The second router, ASUS AX86S, whose WAN port connects to TP-link router's LAN port, has its own LAN IP 192.168.51.1. This router is the one that gives out wireless signals (WiFi). It also serves as a VPN client that connects to a foreign VPN service provider.
At last, a switch is connected to the ASUS router, and it is plugged with an NAS device and ethernet ports that spread around the place.

As you can see this is a pretty straightforward setup.
Right now, an L2TP over IPSec tunnel is established successfully from any configured PC to the TP-Link router, who gives connected clients IP range 192.168.11.0/24. I can verify it connects by pinging the LAN IP of the TP-Link router, and being able to go to its admin configuration page.

The problem is that if I try pinging 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.51.1, which is the WAN and LAN IP of the second router ASUS, it doesn't work, and I cannot access its admin page. I also cannot see any devices connected through ASUS wireless, as well as the NAS under the switch under ASUS router.
My question is, how do I access ASUS router and its connected devices? Including ones under the switch.
If anyone feels like suggesting a different routing setup, I'm all for it too. I suspect that if I connect the switch not to ASUS but to TP-Link router, I'll be able to access NAS device connected to that switch. In the end, I need my network to do the following two things: access NAS/devices under switch from outside, access NAS/devices from wireless provided by ASUS. Perhaps a much simpler thing exist to my needs.

Heads up that I am completely new to networking and I did everything with the help of googling, so there may be some super simple amateur thing that I missed here. If you all feel like lecturing anything that has to do with my problem, feel free to do so, preferably in simple terms.